# return json from deeply nested activerecord object

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got some fairly deep nesting going on in my models where I have

```
-user
   -user_event
        -event
              -location
              -categories
              -attendees
```

I'm trying to return a json object which has all the nested elements returned. 
I can get to

```
user = User.find(current_user.id).user_event #or ,:includes => :user_event
render :json => user
```

but I don't see how I can display the entire hash in one go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
render :json => user.as_json(
                  :include => { :user_events => {
                    :include => { :events => {
                      :include => [:location, :categories, :attendees]
                    } }
                  } }
                )
```

Documentation for [Serializers::JSON::as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: I think this is really close Azolo, unfortunately now I'm getting the error `undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass` which I assume is because i don't always have a category, or location or attendees in each event. Any way around that? I don't see it in the doc you referred to.